# Damaged USB stick?

Tags: usb, backup

I would like to know, if my usb stick is physically damaged. I have some good readable documents, but some folders with unknown symbols and not readable data:

[image]

I would like to backup this usb stick before run chkdsk or antivir scan. But Acronis TrueImage and GhostImage which I have, can't read these data and can't make backup file.

Comment: What operating system is that?  Its unlikely the device is physically damaged, only you can tell us if you did something that would have damaged it, its much more likely the filesystem is just corrupt.

Comment: Are those file names or tire marks? Did you drive over your USB stick?

Comment: It is Win 7 and screen is from Total Commander (file manager). I wonder that USB stick is in this state, I do nothing for corrupt file system.
These chars are not correct names of folders and files, this is tire marks. I think, that file system is corrupt. But how can I backup stick before working with it?